# Specific question Laravel Database Homepage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I started using Laravel few days before.

I'm actually struggling with a problem, I created a homepage and I want to replace some text of the page with content from my database.
So how do I create a model/controller, and after that I will make an admin panel, so I can edit them.

The only tutorials/docs I see are for making a form/post to create users

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vy4XJ.png)

In basic php it's easy you just do a pdo connection and then a fetch and you use your date as you want. How do you do it in laravel ?

Comment: By the way the most important question is, how to display them in the blade index page

Comment:  Hello Mo, welcome to SO and Laravel, What would you like displayed on the index blade page? Please edit your question to better explain what exactly you'd like done

Comment: @DerickMasai I add an example and a bit more information about what I mean

Comment: Oh, a fetch is easy in Laravel, let me post an answer to escape the comment character limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch data from the DB in Laravel can be done in 1 of two ways, 1. using a Model (the best way) or using a Query Builder, which is much more familiar to those migrating from pure PHP.

1. Using a Model

Create a model using `php artisan make:Model` (change Model with a name of your choosing) then open the model once created (found in `app/Http/Models`) and add the following under `use HasFactory;`:

```
protected $table = 'your_table_name';
protected $primaryKey = 'id'; // This is the column you usually set to PRIMARY
public $timestamps = true;
protected $fillable = [
    'table_column',
    'table_column',
];
```

To use the Model, import it into your Controller file like so `use App\Models\Model;` and then use it as so:

```
$flights = Flight::where('destination', 'Paris')->get();
```

Learn more about Models in Laravel [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#collections).

2. Using a Query Builder, not best practice

Import the DB facade in the controller like so `use DB;` then call upon it like so:

```
$db = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'John')->first();
```

Learn more about the Query Builder [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries).

I hope this helps, if not let me know how I can assist further.